# scala json4s handling null values

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have a case class

```
case class Test(a: String, b: Option[Double])

object TestSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Test] (format => ({
case jv: JValue =>
  val a = (jv \ "a").extract[String]
  val b = (jv \ "b").extractOpt
  Test(a, b)
},{
  case tst: Test =>
   tst.b match {
    case Some(x) => ("a" -> "test") ~ ("b" -> x)
    case None => ("a" -> "test") ~ ("b" -> "NA")
   }
}))
```

When b is available, the result I get is:  `{a: "test", b: 1.0}`

When b = None, the result I get is: `{a: "test"}`

The second result throws an exception in the first partial function since it cannot find b.
How can I ensure my code does not fail and instead treat the missing b value of json as None?

I am using json4s 3.2.10 and not 3.2.11 so I cannot use the preserveEmpty fields option.

Comment: Could you paste your exception in full

Comment: I cannot reproduce an error. Maybe you can post how you use the serializer? Tested the following with json4s native 2.11 v 3.2.10: http://pastebin.com/fX8uW7Wq

Comment: I checked the versions. 3.2.10 hides null values...they introduced a new option in 3.2.11 to preserve empty values.